# How to FTP to a Azure WebApp Deployment Slot file system

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure WebApp and have added a deployment slot for my staging environment. I need to FTP to the deployment slot, however there seems to be only a single FTP user which always connect to the file system of the main webapp.

If I set the FTP user on the deployment slot app then it overwrites the main FTP user.

How can I FTP to the file system of the Deployment slot?

Comment: Ok, I finally found out that Kudu has a drag and drop option for adding new files (the UI only has an Edit icon). So this gets around the lack of an FTP option and I can access the file system on the Deployment slot. I am still curious how one would FTP tho...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use what are referred to as *Site-Level* Credentials.  Details on the difference between *User-Level* and *Site-Level* credentials is available [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-credentials).

Site-Level credentials are specific to your site and since a deployment slot is really just another site, you get the level of granularity you're looking for.

To get the Site-Level credentials for your web app, download the *Publish Settings* file for your site.  You can do this from the web app blade in the portal by clicking on **More -> Get Publish Profile**.  Repeat this from the web app blade for your deployment slot to get the Site-Level credentials for that web app (slot).

[image]

In the Publish Settings file, you need the **publishUrl**, **userName**, and **userPWD** from the FTP profile.  Note, there are two profiles in the Publish Settings file, *Web Deploy* and *FTP*.  Make sure you're looking a the FTP profile in the Publish Settings file

[image]

The publishUrl will be the same for your production web app and the web app in your deployment slot.  However, the **userName** and **userPWD** will be different for each.

To use these credentials in an FTP client such as FileZilla, simply plug these values into the **Host**, **Username**, and **Password** fields as shown here.

[image]

You also need to enable FTP for the slot, under *Configuration > General settings*

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply - it was very difficult finding that information anywhere!

Comment: always fails with  
Command:  PASS ************************************************************
Error:          Could not read from socket: ECONNRESET - Connection reset by peer
Error:          Could not connect to server

Answer (score 3):

To get the publishing profile respective to a slot, for example , as queried in this thread, we could have the following cmdlet utilized.

```
Get-AzureRMWebAppSlotPublishingProfile -ResourceGroupName Default-Web-EastUS -Name propertiesdemo -OutputFile none -Slot dev
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe I'm dumb, but I couldn't get this to work....kept saying connection refused.  Well, it turns out, that even though Azure provides the user/pass and URL, you **still have to enable** the FTP service in the `General Settings` (under Configuration)**[image]

normally, this set disabled, and until you enable it, your FTP creds won't work......good luck finding any documentation telling you that

Comment: I've edited the accepted answer to include this.